# Java regex: how to select words starting with a specific letter and is x number of characters long?

Tags: java, regex

This is the code I wrote that selects all names starting from A:

```
String longString = "Amal Kamal Jamal Amitha Farook Amani Tom Adele George Ariana";
String pattern = "(?i)(\\s|^)[a][A-Za-z]+(\\s|$)";
Pattern checkRegex = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher regexMatcher = checkRegex.matcher(longString);
while (regexMatcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(regexMatcher.start() + " : " + regexMatcher.group());
}
```

Output is as expected

```
0 : Amal 
16 :  Amitha 
30 :  Amani 
40 :  Adele 
53 :  Ariana
```

Now I want to select names that are at least 5 characters long. So the expected output is: Amitha, Adele, Ariana.

When I type this only Ariana is returned. And I can't understand why.

```
String pattern = "(?i)(\\s|^)[a][A-Za-z]+(\\s|$){5,}";
```

Output

```
53 :  Ariana
```

If I put a bracket around the whole expression (to say that this expression should be 5 characters long) Then output is nothing

```
String pattern = "(?i)((\\s|^)[a][A-Za-z]+(\\s|$)){5,}";
```

What is the correct way of writing this?

Comment: have you tried to replace `+` after `[A-Za-z]` with `{5,}` ?

Comment: You quantified `(\\s|$)` while you need to quantify `[a-zA-Z]`. So, you only match texts that have 5 or more whitespaces or 5 or more ends of string  (makes no sense of course) after the words. Also, you need to use `{0,4}` as `[a]` already matches 1 letter.

Comment: (?i)((\\s|^)[a][A-Za-z]{4,}(\\s|$)) solved it.



Thank you @OlegEstekhin and   Wiktor Stribiżew :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You quantified `(\\s|$)` while you need to quantify `[a-zA-Z]`. So, you only match texts that have 5 or more whitespaces or 5 or more ends of string  (makes no sense of course) after the words. Also, you need to use `{4,}` as `[a]` already matches 1 letter.

Use this regex to fix the issue (although it is not the best one, see below why):

```
(?i)(\s|^)a[a-z]{4,}(\s|$)
```

**Details**

- `(?i)` - case insensitive modifier
- `(\s|^)` - either a whitespace or a start of a string
- `a`  - an `a` or `A` letter
- `[a-z]{4,}` - any 4 or more ASCII letters
- `(\s|$)` - either a whitespace or an end of a string (note: the whitespace will be consumed, and consecutive matching words will not be handled properly).

You may use `"(?i)(?<!\\S)a[a-z]{4,}(?!\\S)"` pattern to make sure you are matching a word in between whitespaces or start/end of string positions.

Or, use word boundaries - `"(?i)\\ba[a-z]{4,}\\b"`.

See the [Java online demo](https://ideone.com/UEDLiw):

```
String longString = "Amal Kamal Jamal Amitha Farook Amani Tom Adele George Ariana";
String pattern = "(?i)(?<!\\S)a[a-z]{4,}(?!\\S)";
Pattern checkRegex = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher regexMatcher = checkRegex.matcher(longString);
while (regexMatcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(regexMatcher.start() + " : " + regexMatcher.group());
}
```

Result:

```
17 : Amitha
31 : Amani
41 : Adele
54 : Ariana
```

Comment: I didn't understand on which expression the {5,} was acting on. Thank you for explaining :)

Comment: @Enzio Please see my edit. Note that I'd go for the version with lookarounds or word boundaries. Well, it depends on the further requirements.